# Moments by normal stress

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, stress-strain, moment

I am a bit confused with the following formula

why is that the normal stress ($z$), not the normal stress ($x$), is involved in the formula for the moment around $x$, $Mx$?
Likewise, My also equals the integral of normal stress ($z$) and distance $x$

$$M_x=\int \sigma_z y dA$$

Comment: If you look at a diagram of a beam cross section you can understand why these components are involved.  Also, please do not link images, but use math formatting for equations.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a beam along the *z*-axis, with a force along the *y*-axis causing a moment along the *x*-axis (see below).

[image: fig]

Along a cross section up and down the *y*-axis the normal stress varies by location $y$ and is pointing along *z*-axis.

The moment of stress on the ${\rm d}y$ slice is

$$ {\rm d}M_x = y\,\sigma_z\,{\rm d}A $$ where ${\rm d}A = t\,{\rm d}y$ and $t$ is the thickness along the *x*-axis.

Comment: Thank you. 
But i am still a bit confused . 
https://www.mdpi.com/energies/energies-13-01530/article_deploy/html/images/energies-13-01530-g011-550.jpg

In this diagram, does this mean the moment Mx is Formed due to the force Fx ?

Comment: In the linked picture force along _x_ axis causes moment about _y_ axis, and vice versa. The same with my answer. The $M_x$ in my figure is due to a force along $F_y$.